# TP-LINK MFP and Storage Server

Tags: networking, router, printing

I have a [TP-LINK MFP and Storage Server TL-PS310U](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-PS310u). I would like to use it to connect a printer to the local network.

I do not have Windows here (I have Linux Mint 13 on both computers), so I can not install the software of the producer. I thought it could be used also without the software. Maybe I am wrong here.

The device is connected to the router. I can see the IP address of the device (192.168.1.100). I can ping it. I can open the web management of the device (`http://192.168.1.100/`).

I have plugged a USB flash drive in the device. I can see the name of the flash drive in the web management page as connected.

But I have no idea how I could access the files on flash drive. I have tried to connect via Samba (`smb://192.168.1.100/`) or FTP (`ftp://192.168.1.100/`) but it does not work.

It is possible to connect up to four USB devices to the device. So I guess there should be separate IP address assigned to each of the USB devices. It seems that I am missing the IP address assigned by the print server to the USB flash drive.

Do you have any idea how I could access the flash drive (or printer) via this device?

Comment: Usually you set this up using the device interface. I've never seen it work without set up, though I don't have experience with that particular device. Check the device's manual.

Comment: @user99572isfine, what do you mean by device interface? Do you refer to web interface I can access?

Comment: Yes, I mean the web interface. Usually you have to activate sharing services like FTP or SMB in the router interface before being able to connect to them. At least it was like that on the routers I've seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this device and it actually **does not have Linux support, not even for printers.**

The web interface is nothing more than an information panel with an option to upgrade the firmware, and **THAT IS IT! All** the set-up is done via the software that comes on the disk that comes with the device, and the disk and software ONLY works in Windows.

There is a way to get the **printing** to work, but it's a really long in depth hack/workaround to do so, so unless you are a "Linux guru", I don't recommend even attempting it. If you still have the receipt, and you're still within the return time-frame, I would say take it back, and get a better one, you're gonna have to pay more for a device that has Linux support, but it's gonna be so much more worth it than the aggravation of trying to get something to work that is never going to.

Comment: CentOS 7 recognises my printer automatically and suggests a reasonable driver for it. Printing works, but I haven't found a way to use the scanner across the network.

Comment: I've a TP-Link router that also has no published support for Linux printers - any chance of a pointer to that hack/workaround? From a Windows box it seems to install a USB-over-TCP USB device and talk to port 20005, but its not using Linuxy `usbip` standard. Guru level hacking guides welcome.